# Count occurences of word/character in a field

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have website visitor data that resembles the example below:

| id | pages |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | /ice-cream, /bagels, /bagels/flavors |
| 002 | /pizza, /pizza/flavors, /pizza/recipe |

I would like to transform to below, where I can count the amount of times they have visited a part of my site that deals with specific content. A general count of all pageviews, delimited by comma, would be great as well.

| id | bagel_count |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 2 |
| 002 | 0 |

| id | pizza_count |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 0 |
| 002 | 3 |

| id | total_pages_count |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 3 |
| 002 | 3 |

I have the option to perform in SQL or Python but I am not sure what is easier, hence why I am asking the question.

I have referenced following questions but they are not serving my purpose:

- [Count the number of occurrences of a character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155617/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-character-in-a-string) (this was close but I am not sure how to apply to a dataframe)
- [count occurencies of a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286115/count-occurencies-of-a-word)
- [Counting word occurrences in a table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094888/counting-word-occurrences-in-a-table-column)
- [Counting word occurrence with SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15110313/counting-word-occurrence-with-sql-query)

Comment: Please tag your database. Also, is the list of pages/words you're trying to get a count on, known and finite?

Comment: @PhilCoulson apologies - I am using Snowflake - I know the list of words I am trying to get a count on - i.e ice cream, pizza, bagels - BENY gave me a good solution to get all words below but a targeted version would be great too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do `split` then `explode` and get your result with `crosstab`

```
df['pages'] = df.pages.str.split(r'[/, ]')
s = df.explode('pages')
out = pd.crosstab(s['id'], s['pages']).drop('', axis=1)
out
Out[427]: 
pages  bagels  flavors  ice-cream  pizza  recipe
id                                              
1           2        1          1      0       0
2           0        1          0      3       1
```

Comment: This is a really cool, automated way to approach this and I appreciate the quick answer - The issue I have is that some of my links are verbose, such as `pizza/blog/pepperoni/learn-how-to-cook-best-pizza-with-doc-brown` in this case I feel like it would be a bad idea to have counts of `learn` `how` `to` `cook` ... any way I can key in on specific words I am trying to count or would you recommend taking this approach and eliminating "stop word" columns in the df after?

Comment: @hansolo count it then remove the unwanted column could be better ~

Answer (score 2):

I personally like to use regular expressions with groups, then explode into a df which I merge back into the main. *This has several advantages over the `split` method, mainly, conserving excessive memory usage which results in dramatic performance improvement.*

```py
import re
from typing import List, Dict
import pandas as pd

my_words = [
    'bagels',
    'flavors',
    'ice-cream', 
    'pizza',
    'recipe'
]

def count_words(string:str, words:List[str]=my_words) -> Dict[str, int]:
    """
    Returns a dictionary of summated values
    for selected words contained in string
    """
    
    # Create a dictionary to return values
    match_dict = {x:0 for x in words}
    
    # Numbered capture groups with word boundaries
    # Note this will not allow pluralities, unless specified
    # Also: cache (or frontload) this value to improve performance
    my_regex_string = '|'.join((fr'\b({x})\b' for x in words))
    my_pattern = re.compile(my_regex_string)
    
    for match in my_pattern.finditer(string):
        value = match.group()
        match_dict[value] +=1
    
    return match_dict


# Create a new df with values from function
new_df = df['pages'].apply(match_words).apply(pd.Series)

    bagels  flavors ice-cream   pizza   recipe
0   2   1   1   0   0
1   0   1   0   3   1


# Merge back to the main df
df[['id']].merge(new_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)

id  bagels  flavors ice-cream   pizza   recipe
0   1   2   1   1   0   0
1   2   0   1   0   3   1
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Would this be possible if instead of a list of words I would have a dict of words, and I wanted to count occurrences of each group (key) of words. E.g. my_words = {
    'food':['bagels','pizza','ice-cream'],
    'flavors':['chocolate','strawberry','ice-cream'],
    'others':['recipe']
}

Comment: It certainly is possible, but you'd have to do some fancy merge statements. The simplest approach would be to loop through your dict and apply this approach – but instead of `.apply(pd.Series)` you should use `.sum()` @MrT77

Answer (score 1):

I would go this route if you prefer SQL. I typically leave pivoting to reporting applications, but if you really insist, Snowflake has good [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html) on it for you to take it from here

```
with cte (id, pages) as

(select '001', '/ice-cream, /bagels, /bagels/flavors' union all
 select '002', '/pizza, /pizza/flavors, /pizza/recipe')
  
  
select id, 
       t2.value, 
       count(*) as word_count,
       length(pages)-length(replace(pages,',',''))+1 as user_page_count
from cte, lateral split_to_table(translate(cte.pages, '- ,','/'),'/') as t2--normalize word delimiters using translate(similar to replace)
where t2.value in ('bagels','pizza') --your list goes here
group by id, pages, t2.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Going to mark @BENY's answer correct because of its elegance but I found a way to do this in python, focusing on a specific keyword - Assume `df` looks like my original table

`df['bagel_count'] = df["pages"].str.count('bagel')`